# objective-c JSON literals, nested - most elegant solution?

Tags: ios, json, objective-c-literals

Say you do this,

```
NSString *teste = yourData[@"title"];
```

no problem if `"title"` is completely missing in the json: you just get `null`. If you do this:

```
NSString *teste = yourData[@"location"][@"city"];
```

if `"city"` is missing in the json nest, no problem. if the whole `"location"` section **does not exist**, again no problem

However! You'll often see json like this, `" largeImage = "<null>"; "`

In that case, the app will crash if you are using the code above.

In practice you have to do this:

```
NSString *imageUrl = nil;
if ([yourResults[thisRow][@"largeImage"] isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])
    imageUrl = yourResults[thisRow][@"largeImage"][@"URL"];
```

My question was really:

is there some dead clever way to perhaps override the literal syntax (ie, override the underlying message, perhaps??) to cover this problem?

So essentially, make this concept `[@"blah"]` basically first check that indeed it is a dictionary at hand, before trying the operation.

It's a shame because, effectively, you can never use this wonderful syntax

```
yourData[@"location"][@"city"]
```

in practice, due to the problem I outline.

PS sorry for the earlier confusion on this question, fixed by Paramag. below - good one Paramag.

Comment: `But if the whole "location" section does not exist, then ... your iPhone crashes.` - wat? nope. Then you send a message to `nil` which is a safe no-op.

Answer (score 1):

Personally i use with JSON category which returns null instead NSNull so my code looks:

```
[[json objectForKeyNotNull:@"Key"] objectForKeyNotNull:@"Other"]
```

As you want to have code shorter, i think i would create the category on NSDictionary which could be used as :

```
[json objectForPath:@"Key.Value"]
```

Which would expand the path into the keys.

There is some nice gist which looks like it's doing it:

https://gist.github.com/Yulong/229a62c1188c3c024247#file-nsdictionary-beeextension-m-L68

Comment: wow two excellent ideas !  in objectForKeyNotNull you could also check isKindOfClass, as in my postscript.

Comment: have a look at the link i added to the post. Code looks really good and it's got the Null checks too.

Comment: good one, just bear in mind though the real problem is the "it's not a dictionary" issue - I clarified my bad question!  cheers

Answer (score 1):

to check this kind of null , you can use valueForKeyPath:

NSString *teste = [CLOUD.yourData[thisRow] valueForKeyPath:@"location.city"];

it will first check for "location" and then for "city".

Comment: a worthy answer, but one problem is "location.city" fails in a weird way you wouldn't expect, if the first one is not a dictionary but is a string - it's a bit annoying.

Answer (score 0):

I would say this is a problem with your schema. `null` in JSON and a dictionary (called an "object") in JSON are different types of things. The fact that your key can have a value that is sometimes `null` and sometimes a dictionary seems to me that you guys are not following a rigorous schema.

A good design would have the key either not be there, or if it is there, its value is guaranteed to be a dictionary. In such a case, the Objective-C code `NSString *teste = yourData[@"location"][@"city"];` would work without modification because if the key "location" didn't exist, then its value would be `nil` in Objective-C, and subsequent accesses won't crash, and will also return `nil`.

Comment: hi NewAcct, right, you've nicely outlined the problem - **"value is guaranteed to be a dictionary..."**, you can't guarantee that in real life on any project, that's the issue.  (An everyday example is if you are pulling results from amazon, **for goodness sake!!!**, they often incorrectly return the string "<null>" rather than a real null.) As you imply, of course, in an app, you cannot rely on the json being correct - or you're app will crash all day :) (Assuming I understand what you are saying correctly, sorry if not.)